# .NET Directory.CreateDirectory Throws UnauthorizedAccessException; User Can Create Directory using Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, directory

This issue is only happening for one user when trying to create a directory; the code works for all users of the system but one.

Each user of the application has a standard AD account and an account with elevated permissions - the application impersonates their elevated permissions account when creating the directory.

A boiled down version of the code would be this:

```
using (Impersonation.LogonUser(domain, elevatedAccountUsername, elevatedAccountPassword, LogonType.Interactive))
{
    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(newDirectoryPath);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        return Result.CreateFailure($"{ex.GetType()}, {ex.Message}, {ex.HResult}");
    }
}
```

This user in question gets:

> Access to the path '\\network\share\new_directory' is denied.

However, when using Windows Explorer under their elevated account the user can create and delete directories on the network share without issue.

My gut is telling me this is a permissions issue why would it only affect the programmatic call?

**Edit #1**: This is a Windows Forms application. I have managed to recreate the issue in a console application as well.

Comment: Shouldn't that path have started with a double backslash?

Comment: Sorry, I think that was an escape character issue in SO. Have updated.

Comment: So your code run as the same permission which a user has while creating a directory from windows explorer? Must be an impersonation issue, I guess.

Comment: @KeyurRamoliya I've confirmed using _WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name_ just before calling _CreateDirectory_ that the elevated user is being impersonated. I'm not sure what else I can do?

Comment: @CptCoathanger If it is a Web Application and hosted in IIS then it can also affect. If yes then check your application pool and permissions assigned to that application pool.

Comment: @KeyurRamoliya It's a Windows Forms application. I should have stated that in the orignial post. I've also managed to recreate the issue in a console application.